# Where do you locate your IDE or workspace?

Tags: ubuntu, ide, workspace

I'm using Ubuntu `16.04 LTS`.
My computer has 2 disks, `SSD 256GB`, `1TB HDD`.
And I partitioned that like following

```
- SSD Area  
/boot 500MB  
swap  16GB
/     Rest of SSD  

- HDD Area
/home Whole HDD
```

Now my `IDE` and `Workspace` are loacated in `/home` directory.
I think it's not good to use disk efficiently.

I guess I have to move my `IDE` and `Workspace` to not `/home` directory.
When I move them to SSD area, I could use it faster.
Right?

So if this is right, where I supposed to move them?
Is there any location you recommend?

Comment: Be aware of possible limitations if `/home` is encrypted, e.g. length of directory path `<265`. This is a show stopper for languages with deep directory structures like java.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux os, you would install user applications to /opt. This is ideal in your case as it will be on your SSD. 
It is good practice to store data and files in your home directory so that would be a good place for your workspace directory.

Comment: So sorry to answer late. But I guess... should not both(ide, workspace) be in ssd for quick use?